# Is there any way to Clipboard.generalClipboard.setData(ClipboardFormats.RICH_TEXT_FORMAT,*) with a picture

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I want to be able to send text and pictures to clipboard.

How can you convert a bitmap so it can be in the clipboard with RICH_TEXT_FORMAT later I will add text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the BITMAP_FORMAT format type and pass as Object a BitmapData; the 3rd argument is whether the data should be serializeable (for use in another AIR app) - the function signature is:

```
public class Clipboard
{
    public function setData(format:String, data:Object, serializable:Boolean = true):Boolean
}
```

... in context:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(400, 50, false, 0);
bitmapData.perlinNoise(10, 50, 3, (Math.random() * 255) | 0, true, true);

Clipboard.generalClipboard.clear();
Clipboard.generalClipboard.setData(ClipboardFormats.BITMAP_FORMAT, bitmapData, false);
```

... run then paste in any graphics editor.

- [Link to adobe ref page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html#setData%28%29)

  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, but will this also be able to copy both text and images?

Comment: Depending on the type of data you want to copy you use the appropriate format - The formats are listed in the link above. Your function should decide which to use.

Comment: Thing is, I need both text and picture in the same clipboard data, not seperately.

Comment: Oh ok, you'll need to use RTF as you originally mentioned in your post... I can't help you with that, you'll need to parse rtf yourself unless you can find an already written library for that... The best I can do is point you to the rtf spec sheet http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10725 you'll have to begin with that and ask more questions here on SO, good luck :)